# How to compute Color Schemes on the RYB model?

Tags: color-scheme, hsl

On the RGB/CMY model it's easy, as they use the same color wheel as the HSL model. Therefore, given the Hue value on the HSL model, you just need to increase it by 180 (modulo 360) to obtain the complementary color, or increase and decrease by 120 (always modulo 360) to obtain a triadic color scheme.

But how can it be computed with the RYB model? I saw that the Adobe website (https://color.adobe.com/it/create/color-wheel) uses it, and another website (https://www.sessions.edu/color-calculator/) allows to switch from the RYB to the RGB/CMY model.

If it was possible to reproduce the Hue value of the HSL model in some way to the RYB (so obtaining a value from 0 to 360 that represents the circle) it would be useful, but I couldn't find anything like it.